# How to unit test a EntityCollectionServiceBase in @ngrx/data?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ngrx, ngrx-data

I have a dummy service:

```
export class PatientService extends EntityCollectionServiceBase<Patient> {
  constructor(serviceElementsFactory: EntityCollectionServiceElementsFactory) {
    super('Patient', serviceElementsFactory);
  }
}
```

I have the following test:

```
describe('PatientService', () => {
  let service: PatientService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
    service = TestBed.inject(PatientService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

And it gives me:

`NullInjectorError: No provider for EntityCollectionServiceElementsFactory`

So I updated as follows:

```
describe('PatientService', () => {
  let service: PatientService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [EntityDataModuleWithoutEffects.forRoot(entityConfig)],
      providers: [provideMockStore()],
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(PatientService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

But now it gives me:

`NullInjectorError: No provider for ScannedActionsSubject!`

How can I properly fix my test?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Updated 2022-08-06

Because of changes in the latest version of `ngrx`, you need to import an empty store modules and `HttpClientTestingModule`.

Please check the example below:

```js
describe('PatientService', () => {
  let service: PatientService;

  beforeEach(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        PatientService, // <- your entity collection service

        // a way to mock the store selectors
        provideMockStore(),
      ],
      imports: [
        EntityDataModule.forRoot({
          entityMetadata: {
            Patient: {}, // <- change to your entity
          },
          pluralNames: {
            Patient: 'Patients',  // <- change to your entity
          },
        }),

        // can be kept as it is if there are no more dependencies
        StoreModule.forRoot({}),
        EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
        HttpClientTestingModule,
      ],
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(PatientService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

### Original answer

Yep, you are very close, do like that. You need to provide in testbed everything what is required for the configuration.

In our case it means that `PatientService` should be provided as the testing unit and `EntityCollectionServiceElementsFactory` should be provided as its dependency.

But `EntityCollectionServiceElementsFactory` has own dependencies: `EntityDispatcherFactory`, `EntityDefinitionService`, `EntitySelectorsFactory` and `EntitySelectors$Factory`. Which we don't want to provide because they might have own dependencies making our live worse.

To fix it let's simply sub `EntityCollectionServiceElementsFactory`.

```js
describe('PatientService', () => {
  let service: PatientService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        PatientService,
        {
          provide: EntityCollectionServiceElementsFactory,
          // our stub
          useValue: {
            methodsToFake: jasmine.createSpy(),
            // ....
          },
        },
      ],
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(PatientService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Also to avoid the pain of mocking dependencies and its methods in future you can use [ng-mocks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-mocks). Then the test could looks like that:

```js
describe('PatientService', () => {
  let service: PatientService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        PatientService,
        {
          provide: EntityCollectionServiceElementsFactory,
          useValue: MockService(EntityCollectionServiceElementsFactory),
        },
      ],
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(PatientService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried with ngmocks but is retrieving TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'dispatcher' of 'serviceElementsFactory.create(...)' as it is undefined.

Comment: Please ask a question with a code sample and share here its link. I'll check why it doesn't work.

Comment: @CloscaCostelIoan, did you ever figure out the solution to your problem?

Comment: could you submit an issue on https://github.com/help-me-mom/ng-mocks with a failing example?

Comment: I've updated the answer which includes a solution for the latest `ngrx` version.

Answer (score 2):

In case you just need to get rid of the errors, you can import all the required modules like this:

```
   beforeEach(() => {
     TestBed.configureTestingModule({
       imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, EffectsModule.forRoot([]), StoreModule.forRoot({}), EntityDataModule.forRoot(entityConfig)],
     });
     service = TestBed.inject(PatientService);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to setup the whole data module, as you would in a "normal Angular module".

This means, providing a store, effects, and the data entity.

There could be a better way, but... i don't know ‍♂️