# TypeError: serviceElementsFactory.create is not a function at new EntityCollectionServiceBase

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have added a service to a component that is injected in the constructor

The service is declared like this

```
export class MileageTrackingManagmentService extends EntityCollectionServiceBase<MileageTrackingManagment>
```

I'm trying to update the tests so that the "should create" will not fail

```
 describe('MileageTrackingComponent', () => {
  let component: MileageTrackingComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MileageTrackingComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MileageTrackingComponent],
      providers: [MileageTrackingManagmentService,
        {
          provide: MileageTrackingManagmentService,
          useValue: {
            methodsToFake: jasmine.createSpy(),
          },
        }
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();

  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MileageTrackingComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

When I run the "should create" method I get the following error

```
> TypeError: serviceElementsFactory.create is not a function
>     at new EntityCollectionServiceBase (http://localhost:9976/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@ngrx/data/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/ngrx-data.js:2259:53)
>     at new MileageTrackingManagmentService (http://localhost:9976/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/shared/services/mileage-tracking-managment.service.ts:18:9)
>     at Object.MileageTrackingManagmentService_Factory [as factory] (ng:///MileageTrackingManagmentService/ɵfac.js:4:10)
>     at R3Injector.hydrate (http://localhost:9976/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:11438:1)
>     at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:9976/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:11257:1)
>     at NgModuleRef$1.get (http://localhost:9976/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:25332:1)
>     at Object.get (http://localhost:9976/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:25046:1)
>     at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (http://localhost:9976/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:3342:1)
>     at getOrCreateInjectable (http://localhost:9976/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:3454:1)
>     at ɵɵdirectiveInject (http://localhost:9976/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:14737:1)
```

I have checked similar questions to get other previous errors but I'm very new to karma-jasmine and have not found how to solve this

- https://pretagteam.com/question/how-to-unit-test-a-entitycollectionservicebase-in-ngrxdata
- [How to unit test a EntityCollectionServiceBase in @ngrx/data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62046207/how-to-unit-test-a-entitycollectionservicebase-in-ngrx-data)
- [Angular Jasmine this service method is a not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65711512/angular-jasmine-this-service-method-is-a-not-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

Two minutes after posting I found the solution: change `methodsToFake` to `create` or the method that is failing

```
useValue: {
    create: jasmine.createSpy(),
},
```